# Pass data received from api request to directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 1.4.2 and I have a directive that I have created that I am using on one of my web pages.  The page that gets served that contains the directive as an element on the page makes an API request over HTTP to get a resource, I want to pass this resource to the directive's scope like so...

```
<custom-element obj="myController.obj">
</custom-element>
```

My directive code would look something like this...

```
angularModule
.directive("customElement", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: "dirController",
        scope: {
            obj: "="
        }
    }
});
```

This directive would receive the object in its scope as *obj*.

The object is undefined if I try to access it in *dirController*, I believe this is because the page (and thus the element that is created from the directive) is rendered and created before the API request finished.  I am wondering what the best way is to pass the object received from the API request and pass it into the isolated scope of *customeElement*.

Comment: one of the quick way would be, you could have `watcher` inside your directive on `obj` OR you could use `ng-if` directive on your element, to render it once you have data  like `ng-if="myController.obj"` on directive element

Comment: where do you see that its undefined? it might be undefined initially while loading but if you use {{obj.prop}} in the directives template it should show the value ones data is loaded

Comment: @PankajParkar the ng-if method worked, thanks!

Comment: Should i add it as an answer??

Comment: You can add it, I would up-vote it, but I think that the answer given below is slightly more proper.  I think you were referring to something similar in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//EDITED

I also encoured this kind of problem, you can use something like this in your directive's controller to wait that your "obj" object has been instanciated (by an asynchronus call for example) :

```
$scope.$watch('obj', function(newValue) {
  if(newValue != undefined){
    // do what you want her
  } 
});
```

Comment: Does this go in the directive's controller?